# Alpine JS fetch data - limit x-for iteration results and store data for later use

Tags: json, fetch, iteration, slider, alpine.js

Alpine JS fetch data
How we should do to limit x-for iteration (like the json have 10 results but i want to show only five) and store data for later use with another script outside like a slider to add data ater each slide.
In short, retrieve the json response data to load the next slider image only when the slider arrow will be clicked or the slider will be swiped.

The data should be stored for use in javascript.

HTML:

```
<div class="main" x-data="init()">
  <h4 class="font-xxlarge">Movie search in Alpine.js</h4>
  <div class="searchArea">
    <input
      class="inputText"
      type="text" 
      placeholder="Type to search a fact"
      x-model="q"
      @keyup.enter="search()"
    />
    <button class="bg-default" @click="search()">Search</button>
    <br><br>
  </div>
  <div>
   <template x-for="result in results">
      <div class="movieCard">
        <div>
          <img x-bind:src="result.Poster" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="movieDetailItem">
            <span style="padding-right: 5px">Title:</span
            ><span><b x-text="result.Title">Man of Steel</b></span>
          </div>
          <div class="movieDetailItem">
            <span style="padding-right: 5px">Year:</span
            ><span><b x-text="result.Year">2008</b></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
```

JS:

```
 function init() {
    return {
      results: [],
      q: "",
      search: function () {
        fetch(
          "https://www.omdbapi.com/?&apikey=e1a73560&s=" + this.q + "&type=movie"
        )
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((response) => (this.results = response.Search))
          .then(response => console.log(response))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        
        // console.log(response);
      },
    };
  }
```

Codepen example: [https://codepen.io/onigetoc/pen/yLKXwQa](https://codepen.io/onigetoc/pen/yLKXwQa?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1):

Alpine.js calls this feature [getters](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/data#getters), they return data based on other states. Let's say we have `startIndex` and `endIndex` variables, then we can do a simple filtering with `filter()` in the getter method, that returns the items between these two indexes.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<script>
function init() {
  return {
    results: ['#1', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#5'],
    startIndex: 2,
    endIndex: 4,
    
    get filteredResults() {
      return this.results.filter((val, index) => {
        return index >= this.startIndex && index <= this.endIndex
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<div class="main" x-data="init()">
  Items:<br>
  <template x-for="result in results">
    <span x-text="`${result} `"></span>
  </template>
  <br><br>
  
  Filtered items between index: <span x-text="`${startIndex} and ${endIndex}`"></span>:<br>
  <template x-for="result in filteredResults">
    <span x-text="`${result} `"></span>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank's i finally figured how to make it work with your example. https://codepen.io/onigetoc/pen/abYydpj
Now i have to find how to store the results for using it later with javascript actions.